# Python script isn't working

Tags: python

I wrote this script for a program I'm writing ever since I changed careers but running into a lot of issues with it. Supposed to take a string and encrypt it with a key. Not sure where to begin with troubleshooting as I'm new to programming so came here for help. Maybe if you can just point me in the write direction where to begin?

This is the error I get but looks fine.

```
$ python temp.py -p "ThisIsATestOfMyCode" -k "testtest"
  File "encrypt.py", line 37
    else:
       ^
```

This is my code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys, argparse

def encrypt(varAble1, varAble2):
    varAble1_size = len(varAble1)/float(len(varAble2))
    if str(varAble1_size).split(".")[1] == "0":
    else:
        while str(varAble1_size).split(".")[1] != "0":
            varAble1 +== "@"
            varAble1_size = len(varAble1)/float(len(varAble2))
    code = []
    varAble1 = list(varAble1)
    varAble2 = list(varAble2))
    multiply_size = int(str((varAble1_size)).spliy(".")[0]) * 8
    while varAble1 != []:
        p_varAble1 = varAble1[0:8]
        p_varAble2 = varAble2[0:8]
        temp_list = []
        for i in xrange(0,8):
            if type(p_varAble2[i]) == type(int):
                new_ct = (ord(chr(p_varAble2[i])) ^ ord(p_varAble1[0]))
            else:
            new_ct = (ord(p_varAble2[i]) ^ ord(p_varAble1[0]))
            code.append(new_ct)
            temp_list.append(new_ct)
            varAble1.pop(0)
            p_varAble1.pop(0)
            varAble2 = temp_list
       varAble2.reverse()
    code.reverse()
    varAble1 = code.reverse()
    code_text = []
    for i in code:
        hex_value = hex(i)
        if len(hex_value) != 4:
            code_text.append("0" + hex(i)[2:])
        else:
            code_text.append(hex(i)[2:])
            varAble2 += i
    code_text = "".join(code_text).upper()
    return code_text

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Encrypt things")
    parser.add_argument("-p", "--var1",help="String to enc",metavar='<pt>', required=True)
    parser.add_argument("-k", "--var2", help="8 length key to encrypt with", metavar='<key>', required=True)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    var1 = args.var1
    var2 = args.var2
    hash = encrypt(var1, var2)
    print "[+] Encrypted using %s [+]\n%s" % (var2, hash)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: As well as Andrew's answer Your line after "new_ct" else is not indented correctly. It might be that your code has some lines indented using spaces and some using tabs.

Comment: There's something weird about this program. It doesn't seem to be written by someone new to Python. On the other hand it's got beginners mistakes in it. If you want to learn Python, start with trivial programs rather than copying code. Make small steps. This makes it easier to spot your mistakes.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before you posting any question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The block of `if str(varAble1_size).split(".")[1] == "0":` is empty, so you will need to add a `pass` statement after it. Keef Baker is also correct in spotting that the block for `else:` on line 37 is not properly indented.

Comment: Ahhhh! Thank you both!

Answer (score 2):

You have to indent your code after `else` :

```
else:
    new_ct = (ord(p_varAble2[i]) ^ ord(p_varAble1[0]))
```

And as Andrew Kulpa noted, the block after

```
if str(varAble1_size).split(".")[1] == "0":
```

is empty, so you either need to do something in that block, or add a `pass` statement.

Python does not use brackets but indentation for control flow. 
In your code, the Python interpreter sees an **else** but no statement for it, so it throws an error. 
See more about control flow here : https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html